# Salvar dataset C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net, dataset

Estou buscando várias tabelas do banco de dados para um `Dataset` através de um `Stored Procedure` no `MySQL` usando o *MySQL Workbrenck*, mas na hora de salvar somente a primeira tabela é salva, meu código:

### Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Tabelas_Materia_Prima`()
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_ar order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_amido order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_art order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_umidade order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_pol order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_infeccao order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_imp_veg order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_imp_min order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_fosfato order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_fibra order by 'DATA';
    SELECT * FROM materia_prima_dextrana order by 'DATA';    

END
```

### Método para salvar o Dataset novamente:

```
public void Salvar_Procedure(DataSet Dados, string Nome_Procedure)
{
     MySqlConnection Conexao = new MySqlConnection(StringConexao);

     //OdbcConnection Conexao = new OdbcConnection("DSN=YasFashion_Sacoleiro_DB");

     MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand();
     Comando.Connection = Conexao;
     Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     Comando.CommandText = Nome_Procedure;
     MySqlDataAdapter Meu_Adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(Comando);

     //OdbcDataAdapter Meu_Adaptador = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Nome_Tabela, Conexao);

     try
     {
          Conexao.Open();

          MySqlCommandBuilder Comando01 = new MySqlCommandBuilder(Meu_Adaptador);

         //OdbcCommandBuilder Comando = new OdbcCommandBuilder(Meu_Adaptador);

         Meu_Adaptador.Update(Dados);

         Conexao.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           MessageBox.Show("Erro de salvamento: \n" + ex);
      }
}
```

Comment: Você que usar a PROCEDURE Tabelas_Materia_Prima() como um select de retorno de todos os select que tem nela?

Answer (score 0):

A sua Proc executa quando é chamada direto do SGBD? Caso não, da uma olhada se ele não está se perdendo com o nome das colunas dos diferentes tipos de tabelas.

Você pode compor o select por campos explícitos com o mesmo nome para cada consulta. Pelo que parece, o objeto que você salva está conforme o primeiro select.

Você pode usar todos eles em uma View utilizando o UNION do sql para colocar todos os dados como se fosse uma única tabela.